# Sklearn TfIdfVectorizer remove docs containing all stopwords

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am using `sklearn`'s `TfIdfVectorizer` to vectorize my corpus. In my analysis, there are some document which all terms are filtered out due to containing all stopwords. To reduce the sparsity issue and because it is meaningless to include them in the analysis, I would like to remove it.

Looking into the `TfIdfVectorizer` doc, there is no parameter that can be set to do this. Therefore, I am thinking of removing this manually before passing the corpus into the vectorizer. However, this has a potential issue which the stopwords that I have gotten is not the same as the list used by vectorizer, since I also use both `min_df` and `max_df` option to filter out terms.

Is there any better way to achieve what I am looking for (i.e. removing/ignoring document containing all stopwords)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. specify your sopwords and then, after `TfidfVecorizer`
2. filter out empty rows

The following code snippet shows a simplified example that should set you in the right direction:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["aa ab","aa ab ac"]
stop_words = ["aa","ab"]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
idx = np.array(corpus_tfidf.sum(axis=1)==0).ravel()
corpus_filtered = corpus_tfidf[~idx]
```

Feel free to ask questions if you still have any!

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use this:

```
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def tokenize(text):
    # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
    tokens = [word for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
    filtered_tokens = []
    # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
    punctuations="?:!.,;'�۪"
    for token in tokens:
        if token in punctuations:
            tokens.remove(token)
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z0-9]', token):
            filtered_tokens.append(token)

    st = ' '.join(filtered_tokens)
    return st
tokenize(data)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8,min_df=0.01,stop_words='english',
    use_idf=True,tokenizer=tokenize)

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])
ids = np.array(tfidf_matrix.sum(axis=1)==0).ravel()
tfidf_filtered = tfidf_matrix[~ids]
```

This way you can remove `stopwords`, `empty rows` and use `min_df` and `max_df`.

Comment: This is my current approach now, using my own `tokenizer`, but this didn't remove the empty docs if they don't have anything left after stopword removal.

Comment: After applying this function you can sum `tfidf` row values and if they are zero, then remove them. (script updated)